# udocker & ubuntu:20.04 image

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

on my debian jessie I installed most recent udocker. In udocker I pulled ubuntu:20.04 image and when starting installing packages into that container, got this error below. Any help, please ?

```
Setting up libapparmor1:amd64 (2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1) ...
Setting up libcap2:amd64 (1:2.32-1) ...
Setting up libargon2-1:amd64 (0~20171227-0.2) ...
Setting up libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.167-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libjson-c4:amd64 (0.13.1+dfsg-7ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up libcryptsetup12:amd64 (2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libip4tc2:amd64 (1.8.4-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libkmod2:amd64 (27-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up systemd-timesyncd (245.4-4ubuntu3.1) ...
groupadd: failure while writing changes to /etc/group
adduser: `/sbin/groupadd -g 101 systemd-timesync' returned error code 10. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package systemd-timesyncd (--configure):
 installed systemd-timesyncd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:
 systemd depends on systemd-timesyncd | time-daemon; however:
  Package systemd-timesyncd is not configured yet.
  Package time-daemon is not installed.
  Package systemd-timesyncd which provides time-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd-timesyncd
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@lxg1213:~#
```

Comment: Please Show me your dpkg line of your docker file

Comment: And you have to install time-daemon (systemd). Why is it missing? Please Show me your install part in your docker file.

Comment: I have /usr/bin/dpkg and udocker . Still can not work in udocker image...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to have the local time in your docker container (because your docker host have the synced time)?

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
apt-get install -y tzdata
ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Comment: thanks for hint; however, this does not solve the failures above.

Comment: please show me your docker file. It is not possible to answere your question without it

Comment: Matthia, please where I find "docker file", when I am using udocker ? I have only milias@lxg1213.gsi.de:~/.udocker images
REPOSITORY
ubuntu:20.04

Answer (score 0):

Well, I try to answer: udocker is not supported by IT department. That is why I am getting these errors when updating packages.